# How to add read status column in calibre?

Tags: calibre, kobo

I want to sync my read status in caliber with my Kobo Auro H2O(Koreader) but it is not supported yet so the advice [here](https://github.com/koreader/koreader/issues/3814) is to create a read status column then sync the data to it.
[image]

Can anyone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Caliber has the option to add custom columns.
The option is available trough Preferences -> Add your own columns -> Add custom column.

The complete procedure is explained in [this article](https://evilshit.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/how-to-mark-books-as-read-in-calibre/): does it fit for you?